# JMS + Wildfly 8.2.0 Final: The following keys are invalid for configuring a connector: http-upgrade-endpoint

Tags: java, queue, jms, hornetq, wildfly-8

I'm trying to use JMS on Wildfly 8.2.0.
I created one queue called GrinderRemoteQueue with jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/grinderRemote, using the default Remote Connection Factory. Below there is the section of standalone-full.xml config file for jms configuration.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0">
        <hornetq-server>
            <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>

            <connectors>
                <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http">
                    <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor"/>
                </http-connector>
                <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http">
                    <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor-throughput"/>
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param key="host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
                    <param key="port" value="5445"/>
                </http-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </connectors>

            <acceptors>
                <http-acceptor http-listener="default" name="http-acceptor"/>
                <http-acceptor http-listener="default" name="http-acceptor-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                    <param key="host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
                    <param key="port" value="5445"/>
                </http-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </acceptors>

            <security-settings>
                <security-setting match="#">
                    <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                </security-setting>
            </security-settings>

            <address-settings>
                <address-setting match="#">
                    <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                    <page-size-bytes>2097152</page-size-bytes>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                </address-setting>
            </address-settings>

            <jms-connection-factories>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="http-connector"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                    <transaction mode="xa"/>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </pooled-connection-factory>
            </jms-connection-factories>

            <jms-destinations>
                <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue">
                    <entry name="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-queue name="DLQ">
                    <entry name="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-queue name="GrinderRemoteQueue">
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/grinderRemote"/>
                    <durable>true</durable>
                </jms-queue>
            </jms-destinations>
        </hornetq-server>
    </subsystem>
```

For test this configuration I created a new Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Luna, using the following class:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;


import org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory;


public class TestJMS {




  public void Test() throws NamingException, JMSException {


      HornetQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
      Connection connection = null;
      Session session = null;
      MessageProducer producer = null;
      MessageConsumer consumer = null;
      Destination destination = null;
      TextMessage message = null;
      Context context = null;


      try {
          final Properties env = new Properties();
          env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
          env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
          env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
          env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "jmsuser");
          env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "*********");
          context = new InitialContext(env);


          connectionFactory = (HornetQConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");


          System.out.println("lookup: jms/GrinderRemoteConnectionFactory success!");


          destination = (Destination) context.lookup("jms/queue/grinderRemote");


          System.out.println("lookup: java:/jms/queue/grinderRemote success!");


          JMSContext createContext = connectionFactory.createContext("jmsuser", "Logitech550!", JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);


          System.out.println("connectionFactory.createContext success!");


          createContext.createConsumer(destination);


          System.out.println("createContext.createConsumer success!");


          connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("jmsuser", "your password");


          System.out.println("connectionFactory.createConnection success!");


          session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
          producer = session.createProducer(destination);


          System.out.println("session.createProducer success!");


          connection.start();


          int count = Integer.parseInt("1");
          String content = "Hello, World!";


          // Send the specified number of messages
          for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              message = session.createTextMessage(content);
              producer.send(message);


              System.out.println("Message sent successfully: " + message);
          }


      } catch (Exception e) {


          e.printStackTrace();


      } finally {
          if (context != null) {
              context.close();
          }


          // closing the connection takes care of the session, producer, and consumer
          if (connection != null) {
              connection.close();
          }
      }

  }


}
```

Running this class I got this output:

```
18:23:50,323 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) lookup: jms/GrinderRemoteConnectionFactory success!
18:23:50,341 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) lookup: java:/jms/queue/grinderRemote success!
18:23:50,374 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Failed to create session factory
18:23:50,374 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hornetq.jms.client.JmsExceptionUtils.convertToRuntimeException(JmsExceptionUtils.java:86)
18:23:50,375 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createContext(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:152)
18:23:50,375 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at it.vr.pms.TestJMS.Test(TestJMS.java:62)
18:23:50,375 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at it.vr.pms.Base.doGet(Base.java:81)
18:23:50,375 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
18:23:50,376 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
18:23:50,376 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
18:23:50,376 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
18:23:50,376 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
18:23:50,377 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
18:23:50,377 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
18:23:50,377 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
18:23:50,378 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
18:23:50,378 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
18:23:50,378 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
18:23:50,379 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
18:23:50,379 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
18:23:50,379 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
18:23:50,379 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
18:23:50,380 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
18:23:50,380 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
18:23:50,380 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
18:23:50,381 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
18:23:50,381 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
18:23:50,381 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
18:23:50,381 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
18:23:50,382 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
18:23:50,382 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
18:23:50,382 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
18:23:50,382 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
18:23:50,383 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
18:23:50,383 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
18:23:50,383 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
18:23:50,384 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:676)
18:23:50,384 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createContext(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:142)
18:23:50,384 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    ... 30 more
18:23:50,385 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following keys are invalid for configuring a connector: http-upgrade-endpoint
18:23:50,385 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.checkTransportKeys(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1507)
18:23:50,385 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:207)
18:23:50,385 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:867)
18:23:50,386 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:672)
```

I think that the main problem is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following keys are invalid for configuring a connector: http-upgrade-endpoint`, but I can't understand where I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance for replies.

Enrico

Comment: You can try removing java  from entry for JNDI lookup. I also faced similar issue which got resolved by removing java: from entries.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion! I resolve the issue by removing  <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor"/> param from <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http"> element. The code now is able to send message to queue.

Answer (score 0):

Update all libraries on your client to use wildfly libraries but not jbossAS'
-hornet (module)
-jboss-client (it's at bin/client directory)
-remoting (module)
-etc (module)